# How can I insert a date type into MongoDB with iOS Swift (via JSON and Node.js)

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, mongodb, swift

Has anyone managed to insert a date type into MongoDB with iOS Swift (or Objective C)? I know I can store as a string like this:

```
let now = NSDate()
let nowISO8601 = ISO8601Format.stringFromDate(now)
```

But really I want to construct a valid JSON object resulting in a date type when inserted into MongoDB.

Here's a simplified version of my Swift code to post to MongoDB via a Node.js web service:

```
let dateData = ["some_date" : nowISO8601]

        if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dateData){

            let url = NSURL(string: "http://mynodejsurl")

            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
            var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dateData, options: nil, error: nil)

            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = data

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: nil)

            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Is the problem the date format? Or is the insert failing?